# how to redirect site url based on social engine to desired html file

Tags: .htaccess, socialengine

sorry guys i'm new to .htaccess. I want to redirect my site(based on social engine) main page to some html page 
eg if somebody type www.example.com/   it will be redirected to www.example.com/main.html
but i want other functionality working unaffectedly like, if i type www.example.com/login/ 
it will be redirected to login page and after that if i get sign in it'll be working same as it was working previously. 
i write the .htaccess as given below :-

```
# $Id: .htaccess 9977 2013-03-19 20:51:56Z john $

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ 
    RewriteRule (.*) main.html [L,QSA]

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# sends requests /index.php/path/to/module/ to "index.php"
# AcceptPathInfo On

# @todo This may not be effective in some cases
FileETag Size

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

but problem is for first time it working good like if i type www.example.com/ i got redirected to www.example.com/main.html 
and if i type www.example.com/login/ i got redirected to login page 
but problem arise if login is authenticated and get sign the  socialengine  may be work in a way that i get redirected to www.example.com due to wich again i got redirected to example.com/main.html what i don't want this time.
please suggest me solution how to tackle this problem.
Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rule:

`RewriteRule ^$ main.html [L,QSA]`

It will only redirect the root URL.

Comment: thanks for your help but still the issue is same ... after login page(www.example.com/login) if i get sing in i got redirected to www.example.com/main.html what i don't want dis time because socialengine changes the url to www.example.com automatically due to which htaccess redirect the page to www.example.com/main.com 

so basically what i figured out: i want to redirect to " www.example.com/main.html " if i type " www.example.com/ " and i'll be remain at home page of my site if htaccess got a url "www.example.com" so basically i need to put a filter for "/" (frontslash) on my url

Comment: I think you can achieve that by slightly modifying the regex rule.